# How to Dynamically load content

Tags: jquery, html, dynamic

Alright so I've been stuck on this for a while.. I've looked at tutorials and I don't get how this is going to work...

[This is the Site](http://habboforum.ca)

I want to load the navigation option such as "Home" "About" "Contact" into the green content box.

Here's the code:

```
    <div id="header">
    <nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="content/home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</div>  
<div id="banner"></div>
  <div id="container">
  <div id="top">
    <div class="welcome">Welcome to HabShine</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
     <section id="main-content">
     <div id="guts"></div>
     </div>
     </section>
  <div id="end"></div>
```

And here's the javascript

```
    $(function() {

    var newHash      = "",
        $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
        $content    = $("#content"),
        baseHeight   = 0,
        $el;

    $content.height($content.height());
    baseHeight = $content.height() - $mainContent.height();

    $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });

    $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

        if (newHash) {
            $mainContent
                .find("#guts")
                .fadeOut(200, function() {
                    $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                        $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                            $content.animate({
                                height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                            });
                        });
                        $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                        $("nav a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("current");
                    });
                });
        };

    });

    $(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

This is really getting to me, I've been trying to do this for the longest! If anyone has any advice or solutions please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: I have added a e.preventDefault() to the function as it was following the link otherwise. Secondly, please see this fiddle as a demo, obviously there is no content to load at the moment, but in the console in Chrome or Firefox you should see it try to load the correct page. http://jsfiddle.net/jqUxb/

You can use jQuery's .load() function to load a page into a div.

So your code would look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var menuItem = $(this);
      //remove "current" class
      $("nav a").each(function(){
         $(this).removeClass("current");
      })
      //flag the current menu-item as current:  
      $(menuItem).addClass("current");
      //load the content:
      $('#main-content').load($(menuItem).attr("href"));

   });
});
```

Essentially when you click the link, it will then grab the href of the link that is clicked and ajax load the content from the href into your div.

If you want to ensure that browser history still works I would suggest you look at a plugin such as jquery-address

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Alright I'm confused, do I just scratch what I have now and use that?

Comment: If you just want to load the content of a page into a div, say the about.php my code would suffice. If you want to keep track of history which I think you might be trying to achieve I would suggest looking a jquery-address

Comment: Is "This" a variable or would I have to replace it with something? (Sorry for all the novice questions, I'm just really lost when it comes to the navigation.. I'm new to it.)

Comment: In the first instance of my function $(this) is a reference to the object that was clicked, it's a build in jquery feature :) in the .each() loop the $(this) refers to each object it's looping through. You should not have to make any changes to it, just keep in mind that $(this) is without capitals

Comment: also I just noticed that in your html, I think you close the div before closing the section, and it should probably be the other way around

Comment: sorry for all the questions, but wouldn't I have to make changes to the links in the navigation, ex. [ load(content/home.html); ]?

Comment: I have updated the answer to include a fiddle to demo it. There also was an error in my code which i've now fixed. Also you wouldn't need to update your links at all, it triggers when you click on any link in the nav, and it uses the href in the link.

Comment: Thank you so much! I appreciate you sticking around.

Comment: Yes sir. Just need to add some css and bam! :P